# Search files for references to any file in directory using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to search a large code project for any mentions of a large number of images in different file formats, using Notepad++. The images are all located in a single folder, and the sources in another folder. In short:

- Is it possible to search all files in the source folder for references to any of the files in the figure folder?
- Is it possible to list all the figures that were never referenced by any source file?
- If it's not possible in Notepad++, is there any other program that is up to the task?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a job for Npp, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Of course that's one option. But Npp is quite powerful and has a wealth of plugins, so why reinvent the wheel if I don't have to, right?